# Vertical align image inside an anchor with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to vertical align an image inside an anchor element like this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span2"> 
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://www.forodefotos.com/attachments/barcos/17639d1298388532-barcos-vapor-antiguos-barcos-antiguos-vapor-mercantes.jpg" style="max-height: 150px">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have read many posts but none of them works for me. I´m also using a Bootstrap thumbnails class, I don´t know if this is related and it´s the reason it doesn't work.

I have read I can do it setting a line-height but something is wrong.

Please see a simple plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DsQ80oEiHFn4ma4qfNW8

**UPDATE:**
I have updated the plunker. Text vertical align is working ok, but it still doesn´t work for images.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this:

```
.thumbnail {
    line-height: 150px; // height taken from OPs plunker
}
.thumbnail img {
   margin: auto;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Add `display: inline-block;` and set the `line-height` to the parent anchor element to middle align images vertically.

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5jEtK5EWVglrhEkj14e?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

flex layout solution without fixed line-height:

add div wrapper

```
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="d-flex justify-items-center">
           <img src="http://www.forodefotos.com/attachments/barcos/17639d1298388532-barcos-vapor-antiguos-barcos-antiguos-vapor-mercantes.jpg" style="max-height: 150px">
        </div>
    </a>
```