# How to set equal height for image container in Bootstrap 3.3.2?

Tags: jquery, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have [thumbnail gallery](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/), based on Bootstrap v3.3.2

Some images have different height. Therefore small-height images displayed in smaller container, so it looks not good.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust space around images inside image container so that resulting image containers always have equal height, while preserving responsiveness? Not by resizing images, but via adjusting space around it. [Demo page](http://bit.do/Zgi3)

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  alt="Lorem ipsum" src="http://img1.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="product-title">Product title one<br> FFL-050/-100
                </p>
            </div>

   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img class="img-responsive"  alt="Lorem ipsum" src="http://img2.jpg">
                </a>
                <p class="product-title">Product title two<br> FI-10/-11
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Give the `a` tag a `min-height`...?

Comment: Yes, adding `.thumbnail {min-height: 210px;}` improves the situation, but I can't get the vertical alignment of picture: `.thumbnail a > img, .thumbnail > img {vertical-align: middle;}` not works.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700475/vertical-align-image-inside-an-anchor-with-css

Comment: Not working for me. Possibly due to the images is inside an `a` anchor tags?